# How can I create the following drawing?

Tags: diagrams

Can someone help me with this Drawing? i need to add it with Latex to a document and i don't know how to use Latex function properly
[image]

Comment: Which drawing??

Comment: @JPi LOL.  The flower is indeed a nice touch.  Welcome to the site, Mike

Comment: Look at `tikz`.

Comment: I need the representation of the circuit..... not the flower........ pls

Comment: Have a look at [circuitikz](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/circuitikz/circuitikzmanual.pdf)

Comment: Seconded for circuitikz. See also [TikZ examples tag: Circuitikz](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/circuitikz/).

Answer (score 7):

LaTeX has a wonderful package *specifically* for drawing circuits. It's called `CircuiTikz` (documentation here: https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/09/02/tikz-series-pt4.html).

Your drawing is nothing too complicated for LaTeX standards. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz} \draw
(0,0) to[battery1] (5,0)
(5,0) to[generic, -*] (5,6)
(5,6) to[generic, -*] (2.5,3)
(5,6) to[generic, -*] (2.5,9)
(2.5,3) to[generic] (2.5, 9)
(2.5,3) to[generic, -*] (0,6)
(2.5,9) to[generic] (0,6)
(0,6) to[ammeter] (0,0)
(1,0) to[short, *-] (1,1.5)
(1,1.5) to[voltmeter] (4,1.5)
(4,1.5) to[short, -*] (4,0)
;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I hope that my post was helpful. For full documentation see: http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf.

Comment: Why on Earth would you claim this will not work with other engines? There is absolutely nothing in your code to require XeLaTeX. Nothing whatsoever. I've removed the claim as it only undermines the quality of your answer, which is otherwise good.

Comment: On my system (fully updated) only XeLaTeX worked, so I wrote the answer as such. Of course I might have overlooked some detail that would allow compilation with PDFLaTeX and LuaLaTeX as well. Do you have any knowledge of the latter? I would be grateful.

Comment: Worked fine for me with pdfLaTeX. I just compiled your code as was, just to be sure, before editing.

Comment: Can you maybe hypothesize what configuartion my system is faulty and consequently produces the result I have (for me, it compiles only with XeLaTeX)? I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. You don't even say what error you get. Ask a new question with details or ask in chat.

Comment: I updated MikTeX and TeXStudio, now I can compile with both. Thanks for the help (it would really be a pity if my answer spread false information, so thank you for the edit as well).